# Retag [instruments] as [xcode-instruments]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

It looks like we have two tags that are being used largely synonymously, namely [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) and [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments).

It seems that we have two basic alternatives:

1. We could try to shift everyone to [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments):

   - Retagging all [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) questions that are Xcode related to [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments). For example, perhaps we retag those that are also tagged with [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode), [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos), etc. (See below for a longer list of related tags that were consistently Xcode related.)
   - Change the usage description of [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) to make it clear that one should use [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments) for any Xcode Instruments related questions.

   I'm less clear on what to do with the remainder of the [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) questions. Playing around with it, I found I could eliminate most of the Xcode-related questions by searching for "[instruments] -[ios*] -[swift*] -[macos] -[xcode*] -[objective-c] -[nsoperationqueue] -[sprite-kit] -[core-data] -[metal]". That returns fairly sparse and eclectic group of questions, mostly not Xcode related. Glancing at the list, no obvious patterns of other obvious tags jumped out at me.

   As a Xcode developer, I'd be inclined to just declare [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) a synonym for [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments) and let the small minority of [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) questions that aren't about Xcode figure out a better tag. But I freely recognize that I'm biased, so I'd welcome suggestions on how to handle this. But it seems that keeping both [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) and [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments) around (even if we clarify the usage descriptions) seems to only invite further confusion.
2. The other alternative is to retire [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments) and to retag all [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments) questions to [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) . It seems that more people are using [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) than [xcode-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-instruments) for these Xcode-related questions.

   But this seems to leave those non-Xcode [instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) questions under a tag that doesn't make sense (and the tag, itself, does nothing to bring this mistagging issue to their attention.

I'd be inclined to option 1, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: There are non-Apple tagged questions with the instruments tag, like https://stackoverflow.com/q/2873589/792066 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5182185/792066 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23978444/792066. Manual retagging will be necessary.

Comment: Yep, I know about those non-Apple questions. Like I said, if you search for “[instruments] -[ios*] -[swift*] -[macos] -[xcode*] -[objective-c] -[nsoperationqueue] -[sprite-kit] -[core-data] -[metal]”, you’ll get a nice list of non-Xcode questions. I was just hoping that the retagging process had some criteria that they could add, rather than “all or nothing”. This can’t be the first time this sort of thing has happened...

Comment: Well, actually it is "all or nothing" with the system. CM's only have a freaking cannon for these issues.